# AWS CLI: how to enable token revocation on an AWS Cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The goal is to enable token revocation on a user pool created from the AWS console (by clicking through the AWS website UI)

I read these docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-revocation.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/update-user-pool-client.html

And come up with this command:

```
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool-client \
--user-pool-id ap-northeast-1_123456 \
--client-id 123qweasd \
--enable-token-revocation
```

and I get this error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the
 UpdateUserPoolClient operation: Invalid range for token validity.
```

The document has done such a great job of not helping, so I had to ask here

Comment: It's possible that you have to set also --access-token-validity=<value> because was not setted previously?

Comment: @DaniloCacace but they are set.

Comment: You can't do this operation through the console? Is possible to enable it on `Advanced security configurations - optional` section in App Client edit page

Comment: @DaniloCacace  I just checked - nope, there is no such thing there

Comment: @DaniloCacace actually my bad: It is possible on the console. It is on App clients - Advanced token settings

Comment: So you did it? Or it returned some error?

Comment: @DaniloCacace I did it though the console. The aws cli is still returning error though, but vnm